# H-bridge motor controller

Tags: motor, dc-motor, h-bridge, motor-controller, powermosfet

I made a circuit but I am not sure it is going to work. The circuit is supposed to drive a 36 V 28.5 A motor. I am having trouble finding out if applying 5V to [IRLZ44PBF](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91328/91328.pdf) would open it fully and allow 36V across the motor terminals.

And if you find any flaws please let me know. The buttons are actually outputs from an Arduino.

[image: My circuit]

Comment: I hate to say it, but it would take a lot less time to talk about what's right.

Comment: @jonk Please if you have any suggestions as to what to do please tell be.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to apply 5V Vgs to either of the top two MOSFETs, because your gate only goes to 5V (above ground) but you want the source to be at 36V (above ground). (In actuality, the source voltage will rise to 5V minus the threshold voltage and let a tiny bit of current through the motor)

Comment: @immibis What would you use to avoid this?

Comment: @martinkors First, given the all-NFET arrangement I'd advise reading [Bootstrap Network Analysis: Focusing on the 
Integrated Bootstrap Functionality](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-1123.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559692661096) and [HV Floating MOS-Gate Driver ICs](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-978.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559f7cf21200) and then the [IR2110 datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/ir2110.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c80333167e).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no effort to try and understand how either MOSFETs or H bridges work (including no google research).

Comment: @Andyaka I just really needed the help for a project that i need to make.

Comment: @martinkors I think you need someone to design this for you or find a tutorial implementing something similar.

Answer (score 1):

There are just so many problems with your circuit, it's hard to know where to start.
You can be absolutely 100% sure it won't work.

1. Pressing a switch (unlikely to be viable anyway) applies enough voltage (just) to turn on the bottom FETs, but releasing the switch will not turn the FET off. The capacitance of the FET means that the lower gates are still on.
2. The VGS absolute maximum limit is +/-10V (with reference to the Source. So if you actually turn this on you will likely destroy the gates for the upper two FETs.
3. There is no requirement to measure the current through the FETs, but it is a nice to have if the motor gets overloaded or stalls.
4. When your finally get a circuit that works, then to drive the devices you selected to 30A+ you will need at least 7V to ensure they will turn on adequately. You also need to ensure they will turn off when you want. (you need to be able to read a datasheet if you are going to design circuits)

As Gregory pointed out you need to ensure that you don't have the bottom and top devices on at the same time (shoot-through) and if you don't understand what this means you should not be trying to design your own circuit.

**Update:**

Since @marinkors asked why the gate-source is overstressed, here is a circuit showing how this happens with an inductive load. I used devices that are included with the schematic editor, but the result is the same.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY8WtN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The waveform would be as shown below on the high to low transition of the drive input.

[image]

Since V(M_Hi) is the source terminal of the upper FET and V(G_Drive) is the gate, you can see that during the ringing the gate is exposed to -37V. While I've seen FETs survive with more than their Absolute maximum rating I said that this is very likely to result in device failure.

You can run the simulation yourself and change values, but I'd predict you'll see the same conditions. Notice also that the voltage across the inductor is less than 1V, not enough to drive the motor but enough to cause considerable current to flow. This will heat the upper FET, and may itself result in failure if you have little heatsink capability.

Comment: As explained right above the image i am using an arduino to control the gates and i do know about the shoot-through

Comment: Why would it get destroyed by putting 5v into the gate?

Comment: @martinkors It's not the 5V that will destroy the upper FET gates, it's the back EMF generated because you have an inductive load. The upper FETs are source followers as you have them, so you won't see a high voltage (the 36V supply) across the motor ...you will likely see on 3-4V at best. However this low voltage will allow a current to flow in the motor, enough to heat up seriously the high side FETs and overstress the gate (on the high side FET) on turnoff of the lower FET.

Comment: So what's the story of BEMF? It's about the only problem that will not occur. M.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to work for whole bunch of reasons. You will nit have right voltage on high side switches, no shoot-through protection, etc. What you are missing is a gate driver, just google it- there are many options.

also its not common to see Hbridge controlled by push buttons. Are you sure you can press quickly enough to control motor voltage? And why don't you have anything to measure motor current?

Comment: I used push buttons instead of an arduino, but it's actually an arduino that is going to be controlling it.

Comment: Ok. But you do need to measure current and of course to use gate driver.

Comment: What do you mean by "measure current" and do you have any recommendation as to what gate drive I should use?

Comment: Measure current- to at least know what's going on. Better to control it by a current loop. As per gate driver, there are really many of them, just go to mouser.com and pick one.

Comment: So there isn't a specific gate driver that i need? Could i use a [MC34151PG](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/150000-174999/173541-da-01-en-IC_MC_34151_PG_DIP8_ONS.pdf)?

Comment: Funny, you seem to find the ine that is not good. See, it has only one sypply inout. You need separate supply for A and B.

Comment: Try IRS2153 from infineon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83418/discussion-between-martinkors-and-gregory-kornblum).